# MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [listIndexes] on [DB.$cmd]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My API code is using the latest [Mongoose 5.0.11](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) with the proper Mongo 3.4 connection string to connect to the free [Atlas service](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/).

```
mongodb://someadmin:<PASSWORD>@ascatlas-shard-00-00-6fake.mongodb.net:27017,ascatlas-shard-00-01-6fake.mongodb.net:27017,ascatlas-shard-00-02-6fake.mongodb.net:27017/DB?ssl=true&replicaSet=ascatlas-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

When it does this, the initial connection works properly, but then errors out with a permissions problem being unable to list the indexes on the collection in the "DB database".  The user credentials I'm connecting with is the Atlas Admin, so not sure what other permissions I can provide.  Any ideas?

```
profile:mongoose MongoDB connection established +5s
profile:mongoose profiles ensureIndex { identityID: 1 } { unique: 1, background: true } +5ms

/API-User/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:423
        throw err;
        ^
MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [listIndexes] on [DB.$cmd]
    at queryCallback (/API-User/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:223:25)
    at /API-User/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the user has no permission to listIndexes
As per the documentation

> Required Access
>   The user executing the command requires either find privileges on the system.indexes collection or the listIndexes privilege action. At a minimum, the read built-in role provide the requisite permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally removed the username from the connection string, so it only had `password` where it should be `username:password` which causes this error on any database.